# how to determine objects eligible for garbage collection in the given program?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, scjp

Given:

```
 public class Trees {
    Trees t;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trees t = new Trees();
        Trees t2 = t.go(t);
        t2 = null;
        // more code here : LINE 11
    }

    Trees go(Trees t) {
        Trees t1 = new Trees();
        Trees t2 = new Trees();
        t1.t = t2;
        t2.t = t1;
        t.t = t2;
        return t1;
    }
}
```

When line 11 is reached, how many objects are eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: What is `t2.t`? Please provide the definition for class `Tree`

Comment: I suggest you to buy and read the SCJP 6 book. It have 50 pages just from the garbage collection process and it's very detailed and helpful.

Comment: @Desolator. t2.t refers to the reference instance variable `t` in the instance `t2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked how to determine the number of objects eligible for gc. The easiest way to work these questions out is to draw a diagram showing references (t, t1, t2, in your example) and the actual objects themselves. Once an object is not connected to any reference, there is no way for the Java code to access it, so it is then eligible for collection.

This link shows an example and how to draw a diagram

http://radio.javaranch.com/corey/2004/03/25/1080237422000.html

Answer (score 2):

You create three objects:

```
Object "a": Trees t = new Trees();
Object "b": Trees t1 = new Trees();
Object "c": Trees t2 = new Trees();
```

At line 11, none of them are eligible for garbage collection, because the variable t (declared in main) still has a reference to object "a", and both "b" and "c" can be reached from "a".

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code snippet, when the control reaches your "line 11", no objects can be `GC`ed.

Reason:

- `Trees t;` is a field, and thus cannot be GCed now.
- after calling `go`, t2 will equal `null`. However, in method `go`, each `t1` and `t2` point to the other, plus that the field `t` is pointing to one of them. So that no object can be GCed, because of reference chain:

`t -> t2`

`t2 -> t1`